# MySQL: Find number of users with identical poll answers

Tags: mysql, database, join

I have a table, `poll_response`, with three columns: `user_id`, `poll_id`, `option_id`.

Give an arbitrary number of poll/response pairs, how can I determine the number of distinct `user_id`s match?

So, suppose the table's data looks like this:

```
user_id | poll_id | option_id
1         1         0
1         2         1
1         3         0
1         4         0
2         1         1
2         2         1
2         3         1
2         4         0
```

And suppose I want to know how many users have responded "1" to poll 2 and "0" to poll 3.

In this case, only user 1 matches, so the answer is: there is only one distinct user.

But suppose I want to know how many users have responded "1" to poll 2 and "0" to poll 4.

In this case, both user 1 and user 2 match, so the answer is: there are 2 distinct users.

I'm having trouble constructing the MySQL query to make this happen, especially given that there are an arbitrary number of poll/response pairs.  Do I just try to chain a bunch of joins together?

Comment: i guess you have a typo in your question. it's about two distinct users. `I want to know how many users have responded "1" to poll 2 and "0" to poll 3.` i guess it's only `1` who matched with your condition and not `1` and `2`.

Comment: You're right, John.  I've corrected.

Answer (score 1):

To know how many users have responded "1" to poll 2 and "0" to poll 3.

```
select count(user_id) from(
select user_id from tblA 
where (poll_id=2 and option_id=1) or (poll_id=3 and option_id=0)
group by user_id
having count(user_id)=2
)m
```

[SQL FIDDLE HERE.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d8ea/2)